# LAN cable-tester's LEDs fire at 3 and 6 (without passive side attached)

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network, ethernet, rj45

I have hardware question.

I am running a duplex CAT7 cable from a patch panel to a wall socket. One connection works, the other struggles when I test the cable.

Below I describe how I tested the cable and what the able tester shows. Maybe someone can explain what went wrong.

- I connect the active unit of the cable-tester (WITHOUT the passive unit at the other end) to the patch panel and

  **no LEDs light up**. *That seems correct. So far so good.*
- I connect the active unit of the cable-tester (WITHOUT the passive unit at the other end) to the wall socket and the LEDs for cable

  **`3` and `6` (orange + orange/white)  light up**. *That seems faulty. See attached image...*
- I connect both the active AND passive unit (as you would normally use this tester)

  **all LEDs light up except `3`, `6`** *-> inversed result of test before*.
- `G` never lights up in any test

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of the cable shield was stuck behind the LSP connector and shorted connector 3 and 6.

[image]